# Determine time stamp falling between a time range

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to run a job/scheduler, which should only update records in database it is falling under the specified time range. In my case, the time range is from 3.30 AM to next day 1.30AM. So, with in this time frame the job needs to update the records. In order to get this time interval, I using TimeOfDay() function, but my logic is getting failed, bcoz if the currenttime is say 6.00 Am, then "currentTime <= todaysJob.ENDTIME.Value.TimeOfDay" is returning false. I am using the below code to check

```
     var currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
     if (currentTime > todaysJob.STARTTIME.Value.TimeOfDay && 
          currentTime <= todaysJob.ENDTIME.Value.TimeOfDay)
            {
                // Do logic
            }
```

Comment: what did you stored in currentTime?

Comment: You've got to mark the date of the task, because the time component reflects to 24 hours a day and it doesn't know anything about the date...so your morning of tomorrow equals today's morning and your condition is always false

Comment: You could make your life easier by [introducing a Range object](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1845523/540352).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        bool endTomorrow = true;

        DateTime taskDate = new DateTime(2012, 08, 31);

        TimeSpan Start = new TimeSpan(03, 30, 00);
        TimeSpan End = new TimeSpan(01, 30, 00);

        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        bool flag = false;

        if (currentTime.TimeOfDay >= Start)
        {
            if (endTomorrow)
            {
                flag = currentTime.Date <= taskDate || (currentTime.Date == taskDate.AddDays(1) && currentTime.TimeOfDay < End);
            }
            else
            {
                flag = currentTime.TimeOfDay < End;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            //do the task
        }
```

**EDIT**

So I added:

1. a boolean flag, determining whether the task should end the next day
2. a datetime variable (taskDate) saying the date of the task

Start and End are equal to todaysJob.STARTTIME and todaysJob.ENDTIME, so you take them from DB as they are.

**EDIT**

If you could have your job like this:

```
public class Job
{
    public TimeSpan STARTTIME;
    public TimeSpan ENDTIME;
    public DayOfWeek taskDayOfWeek;
    public bool IsEndingTommorow;

    public bool IsTomorrow(DayOfWeek d)
    {
        if (d == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            return taskDayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday;
        else
            return d <= taskDayOfWeek;
    }
}
```

then you could

```
        DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;

        bool flag = false;

        if (currentTime.TimeOfDay >= todaysJob.STARTTIME)
        {
            if (todaysJob.IsEndingTommorow)
            {
                flag = currentTime.DayOfWeek == todaysJob.taskDayOfWeek || (todaysJob.IsTomorrow(currentTime.DayOfWeek) && currentTime.TimeOfDay < todaysJob.ENDTIME);
            }
            else
            {
                flag = currentTime.TimeOfDay < todaysJob.ENDTIME;
            }
        }

        if (flag)
        {
            //do the task
        }
```

**EDIT**

I've edited my code another time: added a method to avoid problems with the DayOfWeek enum

Comment: Start and end time is coming from database, so I can't get it like the way you suggested. Moreover, there r many schedules which needs to be run, and all have different Start and End time.

Comment: @Nick please, have a look at it

Comment: I don't have TaskDate with me, but TaskDate = DateTime.Now; is fine?

Comment: @Nick No, it isn't fine, when tomorrow comes DateTime.Now will be = taskdate + 1, and you'll get incorrect results

Comment: @Nick You should have the task date separetely, or consider using different logic

Comment: @Nick If your "scheduler day" (let's call it so) differs from usual day, these extra fields are necessary.

Comment: In my database, I have columns to check if the job needs to be run on Monday/Tuesday/Wed.. like wise, and based on that i fetch all the jobs which needs to be run.

Comment: @Nick I've edited my post, now it's using day of a week to check tomorrow and today, try it

Comment: Thanks for helping me out of this issue.

Comment: @Nick You're welcome! Consider using upvotes or mark as the answer those posts that really helped you though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET), to determine, if a moment falls into multiple time periods:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public bool CheckDateBetweenDatesSample()
{
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  TimePeriodCollection periods = new TimePeriodCollection();
  // read periods (Start/end) from database
  // ...
  periods.Add( new TimeRange( start, end ) );
  return periods.HasIntersectionPeriods( now );
} // CheckDateBetweenDatesSample
```

Comment: This library is a nice DT encapsulation:) @Jani I noted that you may not want to use a Collection class for checking one time. ITimePeriod.HasInside() can do the trick.

Comment: @Nick Just for your information that this library also uses `DateTime` for computation because that is the only way you can tell a time period. If you use just the TimeStamp, as in your OP, you will not know the difference between **10:30 AM of Aug-31-2012 and 10.30 AM of Aug-31-1900 ?**

Comment: @Anthony Many thanks. ITimePeriod.HasInside() was also my first intention. I used the Collection because many schedules are possible (Nick's comment on Konstatin's answer).

Comment: @Jani But the catch is that all the schedules(time-periods) should be treated as different entities. On the contrary, the collection would combine all its elements and create a big time period for which the . HasIntersectionPeriods() would be computed.

Comment: @Anthony That would be the case with `TimePeriodCollection.HasInside`. `TimePeriodCollection.HasIntersectionPeriods` iterates through all containing time periods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working for me. Correct me if i'm wrong.

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan startTimeToD = startTime.TimeOfDay;
TimeSpan endTimeToD = endTime.TimeOfDay;

if (timeOfDay > startTimeToD || timeOfDay < endTimeToD )
{
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}

timeOfDay = new TimeSpan(2, 30, 00); //testcase
if (timeOfDay > startTimeToD || timeOfDay < endTimeToD )
{
     //will never execute.
}
```

Comment: Start and end time is coming from database, so I can't get it like the way you suggested. Moreover, there r many schedules which needs to be run, and all have different Start and End time

Comment: @Raj You're using `Or` operator while you should have `And`...if your code looked like `if (timeOfDay > startTime && timeOfDay < endTime)` it wouldn't work for you

Comment: now check it, i just pasted the logic. It should be working for all the start time and end time.

Comment: @konstanin, I have reversed his logic. ie he have checked 3.30AM to next day 1.30 AM. But i checked, if its not lying between 1.30 to 3.30 AM.

Comment: You are still checking whether the task start time has come **or** the end time has not become...please, be attentive

Comment: Ah, i got it. Reverse logic would be like this, but the above should also be working fine. Reverse Logic: if (!(timeOfDay > endTimeToD && timeOfDay < startTimeToD))
            {

Comment: I didn't say to negate it, your **!** negation is superfluous...and the *above* should not work and wouldn't

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16070/discussion-between-raj-and-konstantin-vasilcov)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use TimeOfDay property as it is the absolute distance(elapsed time) from a midpoint(Midnight). What is wrong with using just DateTime for comparison? Comparison operators( < > <= >=) work perfectly fine with DateTime datatype.

For Eg:

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.AddMinutes(-50D); //in your case this would be a DT todaysJob.STARTTIME.Value
DateTime endTime = DateTime.AddMinutes(50);// in your case this would be a DT todaysJob.ENDTIME.Value

if(currentTime > startTime && currentTime <= endTime)
{
  Console.Write("Works Fine"); //your logic
}
```

Comment: You missed the very beginning of this post))) The OP said that he's got only TimeSpan in his database

Comment: That does not add up. TimeSpan is just an interval,so what is the basetime that is used to calculate this TimeSpan ?? If you use Midnight, then 3.30pm should be a -ve TimeSpan and 1.30AM should be a +ve TimeSpan.

Comment: OP's got to mark the date of the task, because the time component reflects to 24 hours a day and it doesn't know anything about the date...so morning of tomorrow equals today's morning and your condition won't work as th OP needs it to check, if task starts today and ends sometime tomorrow

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov Also, TimeSpan cannot have a TimeOfDay property as mentioned in the OP. Either the OP is wrong or our Understanding is wrong.

Comment: I guess he may have DateTime with 00.00.000 in his Date part of DateTime variables...He was already said to check the issue you mentioning

Comment: I am using oracle datebase, and the datatype of the column is TimeStamp, but since I am using EF, that property is coming as DateTime. But I am not using the date part, only time part.

Comment: I am confused. If you have a DateTime why don't you just use DateTime for comparison. Why do you want to use only the time part and created a seemingly convoluted logic. Not sure if I am missing something.