# Visual C#, An array of Dates between two Dates

Tags: c#, arrays, date, for-loop, datetimepicker

I have 2 `DateTimePicker` controls named `dtp1` and `dtp2`. I wish to get an array of dates between those 2 days: **dtp1.Date.Value <= x <= dtp2.Date.Value**.

I currently use `for` loop to achieve such a task, but this is not a very efficient way to do things:

```
int c = (int)(dtp2.Value.Date-dtp1.Value.Date).TotalDays + 1;
DateTime[] d = new DateTime[c];

for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
{
    d[i] = dtp1.Value.Date.AddDays(i);
}
```

Is there any better and concise way to achieve the same result?

Comment: What is wrong with your solution, specifically?  Looks fine to me at first glance.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845493/should-i-make-a-daterange-object

Comment: What is `TotalDates`? That's not a property of a TimeSpan. Do you mean `TotalDays`?

Comment: How is the solution you've shown not efficient? What is the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: `var d = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x => dtp1.Value.Date.AddDays(x)).TakeWhile(x => x <= dtp2.Value.Date).ToArray();`? If so, why?

Comment: `var d = Enumerable.Range(0, (int) (dtp2.Value - dtp1.Value).TotalDays + 1).Select(i => dtp1.Value.AddDays(i)).ToArray();`

Comment: Will the last two statements better then for loop!? Performance-wise!? Besides, it's currently out of my league! I need to go research how and why things are such used! Thank you very much for you guys' help!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I advise you to use lists instead arrays and u can use `Enumarable.Range`

```
var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 25);
var endDate = new DateTime(2013, 1, 31);
int days = (endDate - startDate).Days + 1; // incl. endDate 

List<DateTime> range = Enumerable.Range(0, days)
    .Select(i => startDate.AddDays(i))
    .ToList();
```

You can learn much more about Lists [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you elaborate why lists over arrays?  List<T> is backed by an array internally (and one that can grow if resizing is needed, causing copying).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434761/array-versus-listt-when-to-use-which
This answer led me to recommend the lists.
Really the management that can be given to a list seems to me much greater