# How to create an Array or List of strings that contains dates between two DateTime Objects?

Tags: c#

I am trying to request data from a Webserver. For that I need a list of dates represented as strings in `YYYY-MM-DD` format. I have seen these three posts [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847580/how-do-i-loop-through-a-date-range), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126223/visual-c-an-array-of-dates-between-two-dates) and [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738748/create-an-array-or-list-of-all-dates-between-two-dates)  but none of them worked for me. I have tried this and the other posts solutions too:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 7);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2018, 9, 30);

foreach (DateTime day in AllDays(startDate, endDate))
                {
                    string dayX = day.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    InsertEntry(dayX, requestLimit, connection);

                }
```

Using the following Method:

```
 private static IEnumerable<DateTime> AllDays(DateTime from, DateTime to)
        {
            for (DateTime day = from.Date; day.Date <= to.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
                yield return day;
        }
```

Unfortunately the Date that I recieve as a String after converting the DateTime  Object using the first code snippet, looks like this :  `2018-00-07` which obviously is not a valid date. I seem to be unable to find my mistake. Therefore my questions are:

1) Is my conversion wrong or is the error part of the Enumerable creation?

2) How is this (efficiently) done? Overhead is kind of important since this will be running on a server.

Comment: The tldr; of the dupe is that `mm` is minute, `MM` is month

Comment: Use `MM` instead of `mm`

Comment: Wow that really solved it.........