# Is there a type which holds a Start- and End-DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, variables, types, range

I have a method that currently takes a `DateTime startDate` and `DateTime endDate`. It would be really great if there would be a datatype that consists of two `DateTime` so that my method only has to take one value instead of two.

I am specifically looking for a single type, but if it's not possible I guess I have to create my own `DatePeriod` class.

## Solution

After looking into this for some more time I finally came to realize that there is no perfect answer to my question.
So now I created my own class holding the two values, a Tuple would work just as fine though.

Here's the code (almost exact same as in [StepUp's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64783059/13574233), but I use a struct):

```
public struct DatePeriod
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    public DatePeriod(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        Start = startDate;
        End = endDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you can make your own `DateRange` type.

Comment: Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1845493/should-i-make-a-daterange-object)

Comment: @John I'll look into it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the way is to create a class that holds necessary data:

```
public class FooClass
{
    public DateTime StartDate { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; private set; }

    public FooClass(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        StartDate = startDate;
        EndDate = endDate;
    }
}
```

And use it as an argument:

```
public void YourMethod(Fooclass foo)
{
}
```

And [an example of using Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?view=net-5.0)

```
public void Tuple(Tuple<DateTime, DateTime> test) 
{}
```

[In addition, you can read more DTO pattern.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)

Comment: Why doesn't .NET already have this in the BCL?

Answer (score 2):

You can work with a self-defined model:

```
public class CustomDateRange
{
    public DateTime Start {get;set;}
    public DateTime End {get;set;}
}
```

You can work with a Tuple class:

```
var range = new Tuple <DateTime, DateTime>(start, end)
```

Or you can even work with a Tuple type:

```
(DateTime, DateTime) range = (start, end)
```

Perhaps there are even more options, but these are the ones that came to my mind atm.